# How to access style property from the object inside array of objects and apply it to every header of table column in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, html-table

I cannot apply style attribute to table column header. My headers formed dynamically, as array of objects.

```
        tableTh = [
          {name: '', style:{width: '50px'}, isCheckbox: true},
          {name: i18n.t('ExtendedModalBar.naming'), style:{}},
          {name: i18n.t('ExtendedModalBar.profile'), style:{width: '200px'}},
          {name: i18n.t('ExtendedModalBar.security'), style:{textAlign: 'center', width: '100px'}},
          {name: i18n.t('ExtendedModalBar.manager'), style:{textAlign: 'center', width: '100px'}}
        ];
```

render function from TableHeader component:

```
    render(){
     ...

     <th
                    className={header.id ? 'table__header-item' : ''}
                    id={index}
                    key={`tableHeader_${header.id}_${random(1, 100)}`}
                    ref={node => {this.thRef = node;}}
                    onClick={() => this.sortColumn(header)}
                    // onMouseDown={(e) => this.handleMouseDown(e)}
                    // onMouseUp={(e) => this.handleMouseUp(e)}
                    // onMouseMove={(e) => this.handleMouseMove(e)}
                    onMouseOver={(e) => this.handleMouseOver(e)}
                    style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap', ...this.props.style}}
                  >
        ...
}
```

I am trying to apply some methods of array, i.e map filter and so on but none of them work. Please, help me. Great thanks in advance!

```
<TableHeader
              headers={tableTh}
              onChange={() => this.selectAll()}
              checked={this.state.selectedAll}
              //thCheckbox={{width: '50px'}}
              //key={index.toString()}
              style={tableTh.filter((obj, index, tableTh) => tableTh[index].style)} // don't work
            />
```

Comment: what is your `render() {}` of `<TableHeader>` component

Answer (score 0):

Base on your data, I suppose each `<th>` has different style. But what are you doing is to apply the same style.

Please update the style props to the header render

```
  this.props.headers.map((header, index) => {

    return (
      <th
        ...
        style={header.style}>
```

In your `<TableHeader>`, you don't have to pass `style` props down. It is already with your `tableTh` data